# ultracold neutron captured inside fullerene molecule

Tags: neutrons

I wonder if one could capture an ultracold neutron
(energy below 180 neV) inside an equally cold C60
molecule to obtain a composite molecule n@C60. 
It is known that neutrons with this very low
temperature reflect fully off a polished graphite 
surface, which makes it plausible that a neutron
of this low temperature also cannot penetrate 
between the atoms of a C60 molecule.

Comment: Neutron trapping within fullerene molecules is the least improbable step in [this absurd patent application](https://patents.google.com/patent/US20090022257A1/en), so probably not. I'll try to find an answer in the serious literature.